# Marshal C++ Struct as Reference in C#

Tags: c#, c++, struct

I'm trying to duplicate this struct from C++ into C#:

```
        typedef struct
        {
            int id;
            char *name;
        } *ListOfObjects;
```

I've tried using this but it's not importing correctly in the app that's using this DLL and looking for a specific signature.

```
  [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), Serializable]
  public struct ListOfObjects {
       [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValArray)]
       public int id;

       [MarshalAsAttribute(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 15)]
       public string name;
  }

  [DllExport("ReadListOfObjects", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  static ListOfObjects ReadListOfObjects()
  {
      ListOfObjects lists = new ListOfObjects();
      return lists;
  }
```

After I compile the DLL and then try to start the program that's importing these functions it gives this error:

```
  The prodedure entry point ReadListOfObjects could not be located in the dynamic link library thedll.dll.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The MarshalAs attributes are grossly wrong.  But you're not close to that yet, it can't find the function yet.  You only shows the struct, not the C declaration of the ReadListOfObjects() function.  We can't guess at it.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential), Serializable]
public struct ListOfObjects
{
    public int id;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
    public string name;
}
```

Comment: Same error as before.  I'll update the question with how I'm defining the interface that uses this data structure.

Comment: @Dave : That error has nothing to do with `ListOfObjects`, it has to do with the way `TI_ReadListOfLists` is declared in your unmanaged code (probably needs C linkage and has C++ linkage). Show us your unmanaged function. (Also, `DllExport` is obviously nonsensical -- show your __real__ code, not a poor approximation of it.)

Comment: Actually that is my actual code.  I'm using this: https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports

Comment: @Dave : That's for exporting managed methods as native functions. If that's actually your intent, then your question is grossly vague (as it appears that you want the reverse) and needs to mention that as well as the external library you linked to.